# Change field 'Assigned To' depending on another field

Tags: workflow

I have created a list which is autopopulated using a workflow. I have one remaining field I need to populate automatically. The options on the field are 'Network Change', 'Server Change' and 'Desktop Change'. If it is a network change then this task should be assigned to User 1, server change assigned to User 2 etc..

Is this possible from a workflow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Yes, its possible through SharePoint designer workflow.
On item created / item updated, check the value of field "Network Change" or etc. and use step "Set current item" to set the user name in assigned field.

Pseudo code

> If field = Network Change
>
> Set user field to "User 1"
>
> else if field = Server Change
>
> Set user field to "User 2"
>
> else if field = Desktop Change
>
> Set user field to "User 3"

Comment: Thankyou, after you explained this I found the workflow straight away and it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible from a workflow.

Not sure if you're using the out-of-the-box workflow, but you'll need to create a custom one. Here's an introduction.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-32c9c0bf-5e20-4f74-8b9c-d3ea79f2962b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US